# Windows Phone 8, not 8.1, game in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: javascript, html, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

Is there any way to make an HTML5/JS game in Visual Studio 2013 without having to retarget it to 8.1? Because I'd really like to start the project with the 'Javascript Blank App Template' and use it only on a windows phone 8 for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No - sorry. 
Windows Phone 8 Apps are developed using "Silverlight for Windows Phone" only.
Starting from WP8.1 you have the option to use Windows RT (either with XAML/C# or HTML/JS).